# How to convert a js object array to C# array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

in my c# action method

```
public void ProcessArray(string jsonArray){
//code here

}
```

The `jsonArray` parameter receives the string object in the following format:

```
[{\"studentid\":6968,\"enrolled\":false},{\"studentid\":6970,\"enrolled\":true},{\"studentid\":6972,\"enrolled\":false} ]
```

but how do i convert the above json string array to C# object array?

**update:** 
here is the full signature of the action method:

```
pubic json ProcessData(int id, int deptid, int teachId, string studentEnrollmentsArr, string userNotes){

}
```

i dont want to put all the above parameters to a model i want to pass them as paramters.

thanks

Comment: Create a model with those 2 properties (`int studentid` and `bool enrolled`) and make the method `public ActionResult ProcessArray(IEnumerable<yourModel> jsonArray) { ...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke just for curious is it possible to pass jsonArray as a string then internally convert it to a C# object array?

Comment: Yes (see the answers in the dupe), but why? The `DefaultModelBinder` will do it for you (assuming you set the `contentType: 'application/json'` header.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke i think i have given you insufficient informaton the actual signature of the method is pubic json ProcessData(int id, int deptid, int teachId, string studentEnrollmentsArr, string userNotes). i have kept it to short in the original for clarity. as i have updated my OP i don't want to put all these parameters in a model instead i want to keep them separate. reason too many things to edit. So if i want  keep them as parameters then how do i convert that json array to C# object array?